# How to get list of supported resource types of AWSSDK .NET AmazonResourceGroupsTaggingAPIClient

Tags: aws-sdk-net

I'm using the code below to query AWS Resources, Eg:

```
 using (var client = new AmazonResourceGroupsTaggingAPIClient(awsCredentials, region))
{
    var request = new GetResourcesRequest{
        ResourceTypeFilters = new List<string> {"s3:", "ec2:instance", "acm:"}
    };
    var response = await client.GetResourcesAsync(request);
    response.Dump();
}
```

How to get the completed list used in ResourceTypeFilters ?